CPU pipe A FIFO underrun error
Since upgrading to 24.04 I have been suffering from screen "Flickering" or "Tearing". This happens, or perhaps is more noticeable, when playing Chess or Sudoku where the mouse doesn't move for quite long periods, moving the mouse stops the flickering. The flickering is always accompanied with an error in the Gnome-logs;

"i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] ERROR CPU pipe A FIFO underrun"

I am using Wayland on a Linux only laptop, but I have been using Wayland since 22.04 without encountering this issue until upgrading to 24.04. I have tried using different refresh rates (48.07, 59.93 and 60Hz) all to no avail.
Ideas on how to fix this would be most welcome as my chess score is going rapidly down ;-)

This is described with this bug report...
There are two distinct problems, the one I had was solved by inserting
intel_iommu=igfx_off into the command line starting Linux in Grub. This looks like:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=igfx_off"

Your problem sounds like it is the same, the mouse playing a role and that it appeared with 24.04 and it affects only i915.

That seems to have fixed the problem, I have just played my first game of chess for ages without the screen tearing. I will wait a couple of days and then mark your answer as the solution if the flickering doesn't come back.
